# Address-based Geocoding with addresses stored in sql database

Tags: geocoding

I'm new to Geocoding. I need to mark addresses stored in a database on Google map. I have succeeded in doing this by storing map coordinates in the database but I want to do address-based Geocoding. Can anyone please guide me how to do this?

Comment: Google's location API has a method that will translate an address to coordinates. The maps API probably (but I haven't used it so I can't say for sure) has a way to go directly from an address to a map location marker. Have you looked at the features available from Google's API(s) that you're using?

Comment: I found a way of doing it. Thanks.